# Database clone with node.js sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I was wondering if I can maintain a straight clone of my main database, including values.
That clone database would be used for testing porpuses, with the data of the development database.
I've searched the sequelize docs and didn't find any command or technique that solves that problem. Is there a way to do that, or a way around it?
Maybe a way to dump the database into the new one, or something like that.
Seeders would be way too laborious.
I use mariadb.

Comment: Dump the db, restore it to a new db point your test system at the new db Use phpMyAdmin or Mysql Workbench or The command line

Comment: @RiggsFolly for that i would need to manually dump the current database and run the dump in the new database, right? (or write a big script that does that, which wouldn't be ideal). I was looking for a more automated way to do that.

Comment: Dump and restore is hardly a chore

Comment: Yeah, doing that once or twice, is fairly quick, but it becomes laborious when you have to do that everytime you want to run the test scripts.

Comment: Something like the way RMAN does it would be ideal - seems to be lacking with MariaDB. Then again, I guess there's a reason people pay the big bucks for Oracle.